# 9 dots that are 3 by 3, continue the pattern

Tags: pattern

Here's another question the psychology department at my university asked test subjects as part of an experiment. They've graciously given me permission to ask it online.

We have the following.

[image]

Which of the following choices should be next as to continue the pattern?

First choice:

[image]

Second choice:

[image]

Third choice:

[image]

Fourth choice:

[image]

Comment: Is this from a colour blindness test?

Comment: I would also like to know where this is from, but colour blindness hardly seems what is being tested here. The puzzle is difficult no matter if you can see colour or not.

Comment: @SirHawrk well it's a LOT more difficult if all of the blobs look the same. Unless the examiner is colorblind as well

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is the

> **Second choice** because the dots scroll left to right, top to bottom, so the second choice is the only possibility. With each move, a new dot appears in row 1, column 1, and a dot falls out of view after row 3 column 3. Or, as Stiv pointed out, instead of falling out of view, the dot moves from r3c3 to r1c1.

Comment: It doesn't *quite* just 'fall out of view' though - it just cycles up to be the one which 'appears'...

Comment: @stiv Yeah, that is more likely

Comment: Another possibility is that they simply rot13(zbir sebz yrsg gb evtug jvgubhg iregvpny zbirzrag). You don't know what's coming next, but pattern 2 is still the only option based on the previous ones.

Comment: Why is the second choice *the only* possibility? How do you know there isn't a different rule that would produce the same outcome for the first three squares, but a different answer?

Comment: @Adayah From my limited viewpoint, I do not see another possibility. Show me by posting your answer showing such a rule, or even rules.

Answer (score 13):

> I found it easier to figure this out after I rearranged the circles.
> I opened up a text file and listed each pattern as one line of 9 numbers, reading from the top left of the square to the bottom right line by line. I used 0 for the orange circles and 1 for the blue circles and it looked like this:
>
> 1) 000**11**0**11**0
> 2) 0000**11**0**11**
> 3) **1**0000**11**0**1**
>
> You can clearly see the "**11**0**11**" pattern shifting to the right with each step and wrapping around once it reaches the end of the line.
> Thus the next step would have to be:
>
> 4. **11**0000**11**0
>
> Once you rearrange it back to the square form it looks like this:
>
> **11**0
> 000
> **11**0
>
> This corresponds to the second option.

Answer (score 2):

> I will adress to postions with numbers.
> like
> 1,2,3
> 4,5,6
> 7,8,9
> From the first move we know that the dots in postion 4 and 7 cannot hold their postion, they must move as the switch from blue to orange.
> From the second move know that the dots in postion 5 and 8 cannot old their position, they must move as the switch from blue to orange.
> For the dot in postion 5,8 we know from the first move that it must move either to 6,9, as they cannot hold postion.
> Therefore we now that the correct choice is orange in postion 6,9.
> This leaves only the second choice.

Answer (score -1):

The First Option, Its a ''circular'' pattern as demonstrated by the loops underneath the sequence.(in the picture)

The first sequence produces the same answer as the third sequence.

The Blue dots of the first sequence expand right indicated by the red line, Third sequence blue dots converge left indicated by the red line producing sequence two result, **sequence two now becomes the fourth sequence fliped up**(Answer).

Now going according the existing patterns, Down, Down (indicated by the downward arrows) UP UP is likely to be the following sequences directions and this is confirmed by one dot in particular which you'll notice when the first sequence dot Expand up into turning into the third sequence and the third sequence and that dot goes down converge, forming sequence two, Up and Down they then flip left and right  such as sequence one and two, sequence three on the right side such as the second sequence making sequence three not flip when compared to sequence one and two, this is illatrated with the lines labled L/R (left and right)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE (Take the **[Tour]!**) Unfortunately, this question already has an answer accepted as correct a couple months ago. I found it hard to follow your explanation as to how you think the puzzle works, and there's little indication in your answer as to *why* you think it works that way. Ideally, a puzzle's best solution is the most "parsimonious" one, making the most of what is provided while requiring the fewest assumptions or unhinted interpretations; by comparison, the accepted answer is a simpler, clearer, more intuitive solution than yours. Better luck next time!